# Is anyone aware of any English translations of the complete text of Sefer Yosippon (whether online or in hard copy)?

Tags: history, translation

The only one I've been able to locate is [this one](https://www.wsupress.wayne.edu/books/detail/sepher-yosippon) by Steven Bowman, which unfortunately has yet to be published.

Comment: Strange but true -- I am aware of one because I used to own it. It was a 1558 edition translated by Morvvyng mentioned in this article https://www.jstor.org/stable/1453342?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A81ce1887e0fc035269b6d7492027450e&seq=2 I donated it though, so i could tell you what library has it, but that might not be useful to you

Comment: https://networks.h-net.org/node/28655/discussions/3805505/query-english-translation-yosippon

Comment: @rosends Wow! 15 char.

Comment: Nearest I could find is an abridged version from 1671. Can be read here: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=eebo;idno=A46295.0001.001.